# Postgres: how to compare sales current year vs past year with current date

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table "sales"

```
date        revenue
2018-06-01  300
2018-06-02  400
2019-06-01  500
2019-06-02  700
```

and I want to compare sales current year vs past year with current date and get the following result:

```
date        revenue 2019    revenue 2018
2019-06-01  500             300
2019-06-02  700             400
```

What query I should use?

The problem is that I should group 2018 revenue somehow to 2019 revenue.

Comment: You can try to use `pivot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a self join:

```
select 
  s1.date,
  s1.revenue revenue2019,
  s2.revenue revenue2018
from sales s1 inner join sales s2
on s1.date = s2.date + interval '1' year
where date_part('year', s1.date) = 2019
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=97e62d99e54b57809a582c7b21fc4c20).
Results:

```
> date       | revenue2019 | revenue2018
> :--------- | ----------: | ----------:
> 2019-06-01 |         500 |         300
> 2019-06-02 |         700 |         400
```